# How to disable multipart upload for 'aws s3 sync' to prevent metadata lose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am transfering items between buckets. 'aws s3 sync' does not preserve metadata if the item was upload via multipart upload or is more than 5GB. Luckily, all my items are only a few megabytes. How can I disable multipart upload to prevent metadata lose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AWS CLI has command set options to control multipart transfers.

- multipart_threshold - The size threshold the CLI uses for multipart transfers of individual files.
- multipart_chunksize - When using multipart transfers, this is the chunk size that the CLI uses for multipart transfers of individual files.

You can also set these via command line:

```
aws configure set default.s3.multipart_threshold 64MB
```

[Configuration Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

[Reference Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/setting-s3-multipart_threshold.html)

You can also use the low level api which does not use multipart transfers:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key myfile.txt --body mylocalfile.txt
```

Comment: Is there a limit on how large multipart_threshold can be set to? Don't see anything in the docs.

Comment: I believe the limit is 5GB or 5000 MB, but I have not tested this.  The REST API will enforce the max size.